# HTML5 form with PHP action on Heroku

Tags: php, html, forms, heroku

I have a contact form on my site that is hooked up to a Mailgun server to send email upon submit.

All is working fine locally, but when hosted on Heroku, the form doesn't act as expected and instead triggers a download. Any idea what needs to be done to get this to behave properly?

I've attempted making my `index.html` an `index.php` and putting the PHP script in `<?php ?>` tags at the top of the page - both of which worked locally - but neither has worked on Heroku.

Thank you!

form from index.html:

```
        <form  method="post" name="contact_form" action="form.php">
            <h1>want to chat?</h1>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" required>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
            <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="drop a message..." required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="send off" name="submit">
            <h1 class="email-thanks"></h1>
        </form>
```

form.php file:

```
<?php
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';
    use Mailgun\Mailgun;
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message =  $_POST['message'];
        # Instantiate the client.
        $mgClient = new Mailgun('key-xxxxxxxx');
        $domain = "mail.laurenfazah.com";
        # Make the call to the client.
        $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
            'from'    => $name . ' <' . $email . '>',
            'to'      => 'Lauren <example@gmail.com>',
            'subject' => 'Portfolio Message',
            'text'    => $message
        ));
    }
    header( 'Location: /' ) ;
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sounds like the server it is hosted on doesn't have PHP installed.

Comment: My app is a node app - I didn't realize I couldn't have both node and PHP installed on heroku. So while I went through the motions of installing PHP correctly and whatnot, heroku was ignoring my PHP and only dealing with node. I ended up rewriting this code to my node server and handling mailgun that way.

Comment: I wonder why the down vote but oh well. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Lauren F You should put the solution into an answer. You can answer your own questions ;-)